# Show children/find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few buttons and under every single one there is some `div` with `display:none`. All I want to do is to show the `div` after click under the particular button but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Could someone take a look at it please?

```
<a href="#!" class="settingsButton">> button</a>
<div class="hideHelper" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

here goes the script:

```
<script>
$(".settingsButton").click(function(){
   $(this).find(".hideHelper").show();       
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working because find will search for children of the selector, and the div you wish to show is not a child of the button.

Try [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(".settingsButton").click(function(){
   $(this).next(".hideHelper").show();    
});
```

Comment: Oh, i thought that everything below something is its children. My bad then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also find it using siblings as follows:

```
$(".settingsButton").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".hideHelper").show();    
});
```